# iOS: How do QuickType keyboard suggestons work with the UITextInput protocol?

Tags: ios, uitextinput, uikeyinput, quicktype, uitextinputtraits

We have a text-entry view implemented using the `UITextInput`, `UIKeyInput` and `UITextInputTraits` protocols.

Basic text entry and deletion work fine, via `insertText:` and `deleteBackward`. However, QuickType suggestions are not received by these methods, and I'm unable to find documentation on how QuickType interacts with these protocols.

How should I implement these protocols to receive QuickType input?

Comment: Just found this question.  Did you have any luck ever figuring this.